# Parse Analytics: download event data with dimensions

Tags: events, parse-platform, analytics

How can I download the CSV of an event with the attached data, in this case the ID sent by the app related to a specific article read? At the moment I can only download a CSV containing how many events are triggered per day, without any additional information.

Comment: did you figure it out?

Comment: Nope. I asked them in the Google Group and it's not possible. I switched to Google Analytics. :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Apparently it's not possible at the moment and it won't be possible in the nearest future.

Source of the information: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parse-developers/TMWC1v5Doik

Comment: Should be able to download raw data with Parse Explorer.

Comment: That is recent. It was not possible at the time of the post — hence I don't understand the downvote.

Comment: Check out Parse Explorer - it's a tool under the Analytics tab, it allows you to download raw event data.

Comment: I know, but it wasn't included those custom events until recently.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with Parse Explorer - navigate to Analytics tab, select, "Explorer", specify a query, and export your data to either CSV or JSON; the only limitation here is that the number of rows are limited to a 1000, but you should be able to get all your data by running multiple queries on different time periods.

[image]